# How to Convert Base64 string To Video in C#

Tags: c#, video, base64

I'm trying to convert a  `base64` string to video In C#, and save it in the *App_Data/Video/Film* folder . It's not working.

Code:

```
public void ConvertToVideo(string data)
    {
        byte[] ret = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(@"/", @"_").Replace(@":", @"_").Replace(@" ", @"_");
        string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Video/Film");
        FileInfo fil = new FileInfo(path+date+".mp4");
        using (Stream sw = fil.OpenWrite())
        {
            sw.Write(ret, 0, ret.Length);
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Error: The input is not a valid Base-64 String as it contain...

[image: Error When Convert Base64 To Video]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the header info at the beginning of the string, and keep just the base64 portion.

```
public void ConvertToVideo(string data) 
{
   string base64data = data.Replace("data:video/mp4;base64,", "");
   byte[] ret = Convert.FromBase64String(data); 

   ...code
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it can be something else, as that's part of the video data. Specifically, remove `data:video/mp4;base64,`